# How to apply jquery plugin: styler in typescript

Tags: angularjs, typescript

I want to apply [jQueryFormStyler](https://github.com/Dimox/jQueryFormStyler) in Angular2/Typescript.

I call in `ngAfterViewInit`:

```
jQuery(this.elementRef.nativeElement).find('input').styler();
```

My typescript component:

```
import {Component, AfterViewInit, ElementRef} from "@angular/core";

declare var jQuery: any;


@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: ` <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12 item">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-6 vcenter">
                            <div class="position">
                                <a href="#">Java Developer</a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="place">
                                Company name
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-6 vcenter text-right">
                        <label class="radio-wrapper">
                            <input type="radio" name="choose-role4">
                            <span>Viewer</span>
                        </label>
                        <label class="radio-wrapper checked">
                            <input type="radio" name="choose-role4" checked="">
                            <span>Moderator</span>
                        </label>
                        <label class="radio-wrapper">
                            <input type="radio" name="choose-role4">
                            <span>HIDE OBJECT</span>
                        </label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>`
})
export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit {

  elementRef: ElementRef;

  constructor(elementRef: ElementRef) {
    this.elementRef = elementRef;
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    **jQuery(this.elementRef.nativeElement).find('input').styler();**
  }

}
```

Thank you.

Comment: The question is: styles are applied, but it does not work afterwords. How to apply it properly?

Comment: You forgot to ask something or describe the problem you're having.

Comment: What is "Does not work"?